# Video player in iOS 13 and SWIFT 5 is not working

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to create a simple video player using iOS 13 and SWIFT 5. Below you will see my few lines of code but when I run the app all I see is a blank screen. I hear the video but it is not until I rotate the screen that I even see a section of the video. In my project the "video" appears to be just a photo. The video is not even moving it is just the still image you see in the example below. I am new to iOS/SWIFT but this is the oddest problem I have encountered so far. What am I doing wrong?

ViewController:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        playVideo()
    }

    func playVideo(){
        let videoURL = URL(string: "https://www.radiantmediaplayer.com/media/bbb-360p.mp4")
        let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL!)
        playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
        playerLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspect
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
        player.play()
    }
    
    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        playerLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give the frame for the `playerLayer` in `playVideo` method like this:

```
playerLayer.frame = view.bounds
```